# Increasing number of BPF devices on AIX

Tags: aix, libpcap, tcpdump

Anyone know how to increase the number of BPF devices in AIX 5.2/5.3 above the supposed system default of four?  i.e. running more than four tcpdump processes concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I think is "IMPOSSIBLE".

The reason is to read the header file /usr/include/net/bpf.h:

(mine is AIX 5.2)

Then u come across:

```
#define NBPFILTER       4

/* Flags to set the appropriate minor device */
#define BPF0    0x1    /* /dev/bpf0 */
#define BPF1    0x2    /* /dev/bpf1 */
#define BPF2    0x4    /* /dev/bpf2 */
#define BPF3    0x8    /* /dev/bpf3 */
```

So the number "4" is in fact hardcoded into the source code, and each of the above bpfX is all preprogrammed up to 4.